# Detecting 4 consecutive octets in IP address using regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I detect 4 consecutive octets in IP address using regex (with Python)?

For example: `1.2.3.4` is a match but `1.2.3.3` is not a match.

I thought about using or (`|`) operator with brute force method.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you ever accept any answers?  You are a fairly long term user, 2015 on, even if low rep, but on 6 questions, not one answer has ever been accepted.  **You certainly dont have to accept mine**, but this type of drive-by asking isn't really what SO is built on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

```
def isConsecIp(ip):
    octets = [int(x) for x in ip.split('.')]
    if octets[1] == octets[0] + 1 and octets[2] == octets[1] + 1 and octets[3] == octets[2] + 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(isConsecIp('1.2.3.4'))  # True
print(isConsecIp('1.2.3.3'))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using `split`:

```
s = '1.2.3.4'
a,b,c,d = map(int, s.split('.'))
a==b-1==c-2==d-3
```

output: `True` for `'1.2.3.4'` ; `False` for `'1.2.3.3'`

As a function:

```
def checkip(s):
    try:
        a,b,c,d = map(int, s.split('.'))
        return a==b-1==c-2==d-3
    except ValueError:
        print('invalid input')
```

```
>>> checkip('1.2.3.4')
True
>>> checkip('1.2.3.3')
False
>>> checkip('1.2')
invalid input
>>> checkip('1.2.3.A')
invalid input
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with bare regex, well you could try without regex:

```
>>> s = '1.2.3.4'
>>> x = [*map(int, s.split('.'))]
>>> all(x[i] - x[i - 1] == 1 for i in range(1, len(x)))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Regex

Let's actually try regex, simply listing all possibilities from `0.1.2.3` to `252.253.254.255`:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(r'\.'.join(map(str, range(i, i+4))) for i in range(253))

print(re.fullmatch(pattern, '1.2.3.4'))
print(re.fullmatch(pattern, '1.2.3.3'))
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='1.2.3.4'>
None
```

##### Substring

Or pad it with dots and check whether it's a substring of `'-1.0.1.2. ... 255.256'`:

```
for s in '1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.3':
    print(f'.{s}.' in '.'.join(map(str, range(-1, 257))))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex avoiding trying all patterns

```
import re

def consecutive_ip(s):

    if (match := re.match(r"\d+", s)) is not None:
        # Handling first number in ip
        number = int(match.group())
        # Checks for 4 increasing numbers, starting with first value
        return re.match(rf"{number}\.{number+1}\.{number+2}\.{number+3}", s) is not None
    else:
        return False
```

**Test**

```
consecutive_ip('1.2.3.4')    # True
consecutive_ip('1.2.3.3')    # False
```

Answer (score 0):

substract first from all should always result in same pattern `0,1,2,3`

```
def consecutive(ip):
    li = [int(v) for v in ip.split(".")]
    check = list(map(lambda x: x-li[0], li))
    return check == [0, 1, 2, 3]

print(consecutive("1.2.3.4")) 
print(consecutive("1.2.3.3")) 
print(consecutive("8.9.10.11"))
```

#### output:

```
True
False
True
```